# Is it possible to validate someone's identity in a scenario where any part of a publicly accessible dictionary can be changed?

Tags: security, encryption, p2p, public-key-encryption

So imagine there is a server that acts as a JSON storage device. You can read data from keys, and you can write data to keys. The only limitation is that you can't see all keys.

Is it possible, only using this JSON storage as a means of communication, to validate someone's identity? I'm talking rsa keypairs, hashing, passwords. Anything. I've had ideas like storing each users private key by hashing their password, and using that hash as the key for the private key (probably encrypting the private key as well). Now obviously the public keys have to be readable by anyone, but how can I stop someone from replacing that public key and impersonating them?

So just to reiterate, in a publicly accessible database where you have to know the key already to access data stored in the key, how can I validate a user's identity?

Comment: "Now obviously the public keys have to be readable by anyone, but how can I stop someone from replacing that public key and impersonating them?" The more I think about this problem, the more convinced I am that this specific requirement is not possible to solve purely using a universally read/writable keystore. You will need to redesign.

Answer (score 1):

"Identity" is a bit vague here. For example, if you want to be certain that this person is Alice who lives at 123 Main Street, then there is too little information in your system. But private keys, passwords, etc don't do that either. Identity can mean a lot of things.

What you probably mean here is just authentication; that the person is who they say they are for a fairly loose definition of "who" (one that is possibly anonymous, and may not even be unique). If you want to know that the person accessing a key is the person who wrote the key, then your system does that automatically as long as they don't share the key with anyone else. The key is the secret, and the person with the secret is authenticated purely by knowing it.

It's possible you have additional requirements and goals that you haven't expressed here, but if the only thing you want to do is authenticate a user, their possession of a shared secret is exactly how you do that, and your keys appear to be shared secrets.

I'm a little concerned about your comment "obviously the public keys have to be readable by anyone." That's not obvious at all. Just because it is common for public keys to be non-secrets, that's not required. It is completely possible to have both the private and public keys be secrets. For example, I might only give my public key to certain individuals. If I then receive a message I can decrypt with my private key, that authenticates that the sender is a holder of that public key.

Can you explain a bit more what kinds of use cases you're trying to enabled with this authentication?

Comment: I'm making a chatroom using jsonstore.io as a method of storing messages and user data. I'm trying to make it so each user can verify that each of the other users are who they set their username as.

Comment: When you say "that each of the other users are who they set their username as," at what level do you mean that? Do you mean that you expect a way to confirm the real-life identity behind the user id, or do you mean that you want to confirm that a given message was produced by a given user id (in which case you want signing)? It's also very important to consider what your requirements are around devices (can a user connect from multiple client devices, or are they pinned to a single device), and how you plan to deal with lost credentials.

Comment: Note that if the goal is to have no server, only a shared keystore that everyone can write to every location, then denial-of-service is very, very hard to avoid. Preventing impersonation is pretty straightforward, but I could just write garbage data into any location that I know about. That doesn't mean that an outsider could trash a room, but anyone in a room could trash the entire room, and it's hard to imagine a way to avoid that if locations can be written multiple times.

Comment: By "preventing impersonation is pretty straightforward" I mean by having people exchange their public keys through some other trusted mechanism than this keystore. I do no believe you can design a solution based on this one piece of technology.

Comment: Basically, what I've got so far is this. The username doesn't matter, but their public key will be uploaded to pastebin and the paste ID identifies the user. That way if the paste ID changes, the user is different. Clients can request validation of that user by sending data, the user encrypts it with their private key, and the client checks that it can be decrypted with the pub. Is there any way to implement this without pastebin?

Comment: You will need something that either has access controls for writes, or is write-once. I don't believe you can build this with a shared system that everyone can write to arbitrarily (specifically writing to the same location multiple times) and *also* is based on a random identifier for that location. If the hash of the public key were the identifier of the user, then that would be mostly ok for auth but (a) would still allow another user to trash my cert (they just couldn't pretend to be me), and (b) changing my cert (if it expires for example) would change my userid.